# LibOpenShot problem with Python bindings, 'openshot' has no attribute 'GetVersion'

Tags: python, windows, openshot

I'm trying to compile LibOpenShot for Windows, using this guide: https://github.com/OpenShot/libopenshot/wiki/Windows-Build-Instructions

All goes well. Had to manually download zmq.hpp and place it in includes and also the python binding from X:\libs\libopenshot\libopenshot\build\bindings\python I manually copied to C:\Python\Lib\openshot

Now I can import openshot in Python!

However
print(openshot.GetVersion().ToString())

Gives me:
AttributeError: module 'openshot' has no attribute 'GetVersion'

And so does any other method....

Comment: Do you have `../usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/_openshot.so` and 
`../usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/openshot.py` in your `site-packages`?

Comment: No, I am on windows, running my python script from the command prompt

Comment: Oh ok... https://github.com/OpenShot/openshot-qt/issues/2779

Comment: I've seen that issue #2779 but no clue what to do with it....

Comment: Hmm...yes it is unclear.

Comment: I copied the python bindings output to Python/lib as stated above. When I also copy openshot.py and _openshot.,pyd from these bndings folder to site-packages. My error changes into: ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _openshot: The specified module could not be found. But my path does contain c:\Program Files\OpenShot Video Editor\lib.

Comment: Oh I see... I hope you get the solution soon.